# Is there a way to hide, stack or collapse menubar icons?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Right now I have far too many icons on my menubar. I know I can command drag them off of there. But I do need to use them on occasion. Is there any app that will combine menubar items into one such that I can click to drop down if I need to use any of those?

One example is my address book -> gmail address book sync. I don't actually need it in my menubar (it syncs periodically on its own). But when I remove it from the menubar, it stops syncing.

I'd even be happy with an app/script/tool that would leave it there but just hide it from me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Mac Bartender

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time as well and I think I've finally found a good solution.

I'm using [Mac Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/) which is in free beta at the time of writing. The app has a lot of useful features for cleaning up an overflowing menubar.

For each menubar icon you can choose to:

- Display it normally
- Completely hide it
- Display it in the menubar when Mac Bartender is activated
- Display it in the Bartender Bar when Mac Bartender is activated

One thing to note is that it doesn't let you manage the built-in OSX 'menulets' (wifi, sound, spotlight, etc) yet, but that feature is coming according to their [FAQ](http://www.macbartender.com/faq/).

### Messy Menubar

[image: Messy Menubar]

### Clean Menubar

[image: Clean Menubar]

### Bartender Bar

[image: Bartender Bar]

## From the official site

> ### Take control of your Menu Bar
>
> With Bartender you can choose which apps stay in the Menu Bar, are
>   displayed in Bartenders Bar or Hidden completely.
>
> ### Bartenders Bar
>
> Can be displayed and hidden as you want, by clicking on the Bartender
>   Icon or via a hot key.
>
> ### Minimalism
>
> If you want a really clean look and privacy, Bartender can also be
>   hidden.
>
> ### Menu Bar Apps still work the same
>
> Apps still work the same when they are in Bartenders Bar allowing you
>   quick access to them when needed, but keep them out of sight when not.
>
> ### Bartenders Bar can be placed where you want
>
> Bartenders Bar can be moved at any time to any horizontal position
>   immediately under the Menu Bar. Or it can open under the Bartender
>   Menu Bar Icon.
>
> ### Show an App in the Menu Bar for 5 seconds when it updates
>
> Set up your Apps to be displayed in the Menu Bar for 5 seconds when
>   they update.
>
> ### Hide Menu from left of Menu Bar to display maximum Menu Bar Apps
>
> Bartender can remove the left hand side Menu temporarily to display
>   the maximum possible Menu Bar Apps in the Menu Bar.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this thread over a decade later, the previously mentioned [Mac Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/) now sells for $16. There seem to be a number of alternatives however including the free, open [Hidden Bar](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/hidden-bar/id1452453066) by [Dwarves Foundation](https://dwarves.foundation/).

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing an answer!  My only suggestion is that some sample screen shots would go a long way in improving this answer.  Let me know if you need assistance by pinging me (@username) in these comments.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer today

Comment: Hidden Bar works great! Only oddity was that under macOS 12 Monterrey I needed to change [System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Clock > Show date] to either "always" or "never" but not "when space allows" to prevent the date/time from resizing strangely when showing/hiding other menubar icons.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, the answer is unfortunately, no there is not.

Menulets come and go under normal working conditions, some are there 100% of the time and some only show when they are running.

But I've looked in the past and again today, I cannot see any Menu Bar customisation that works on the menulets.